# How to enter multiple input data using an online compiler such as ideone, codepad and compileonline?

Tags: python

I would like to test programs online, as the place where I work does not have a python compiler. There are many online sites such as ideone, codepad and complieonline. However, I have noticed that codepad does not accept input data and although ideone input data, it only accepts one entry data at a time. For example I wanted to test this program on complileonline

```
PREFIX = 'Simon says '

line = raw_input('Enter: ')
while line:
    if line.startswith(PREFIX):
        print line[len(PREFIX):]
    line = raw_input('Enter: ')
```

I entered my input and separated them by pipeline (as stated on the website instructions) but kept getting this error message

```
Executing the code....
$python /tmp/135731949523855.py 
Enter: Enter: Enter: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/tmp/135731949523855.py", line 9, in ?
line = raw_input('Enter: ')
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

How can I enter multiple entries to test my program? How can I enter multiple entries onto these online websites, otherwise is there another, example testing with my code without the requirement of user input.

Comment: Why don't you just hard-code `line = '''line1\nline2...'''`?

Comment: Can you please provide an example, as I am confused

Comment: `raw_input()` expects user input. Why don't you just provide a string directly while testing it?

Comment: just install python and get a real IDE :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, consider to use hard-coded inputs inside your code (turn the "raw_input" function into something you except to get from the user). It can be great solution.

One of the options you have which is pretty close to raw_input, is to use sys.argv:

```
import sys
print sys.argv[1]
```

Compileonline provides you the option, below of your code, to add command line arguments.

However, on PythonAnywhere.com your code seems to run just fine :) You might want to try it there.

Good luck:)