# python 2 error: RTE while taking input

Tags: python

Here is my code:

```
t=int(raw_input())

for i in range(t):


    l,d,s,c = map(int,raw_input().split())
    counter = 0
    for j in range(d):
        if(s>=l):
            counter=counter+1
            break
        else:
            s = s +(s*c)
    if(counter>0):
        print("h")
    else:
        print("k")
```

Error: in line 1, EOF when reading a line

the program works fine on PyScriptor IDE but RTE is shown on ideone/online judge

Answer (score 1):

[This SO post might be helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14167186/how-to-enter-multiple-input-data-using-an-online-compiler-such-as-ideone-codepa)

It looks like IDEone cant take multiple `raw_input()` calls in sequence, and you make two calls in this script. This works fine though:

```
t=int(raw_input())

for i in range(t):


    l,d,s,c = map(int,"1 2 3 4".split())
    counter = 0
    for j in range(d):
        if(s>=l):
            counter=counter+1
            break
        else:
            s = s +(s*c)
    if(counter>0):
        print("h")
    else:
        print("k")
```